# Gnuplot - Plot a graph from the last value of a range.dat

Tags: gnuplot

I have a series of values that are similar to those described below.

```
10  0.10
9   0.09
8   0.08
7   .
6   . 
.   .
.   .
.   .
1   0.01
```

How do I plot a graph starting at 1 and going up to 10? 
...and this repeating itself to the next column.

Comment: Please describe what kind of plot you want more clearly.  What is on x? What is on y?  What do you mean "repeating itself"?

Comment: If you're on linux you could use the command `tac` together with [piped-data](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.2/Gnuplot_5.2.pdf#section*.189) which should give you something like `plot "<tac datafile.dat"` with `datafile.dat` the path to your data file.

Comment: VERY NICE... "<tac data.txt" works very fine!! Really thanks.